# How to set multi default value in type checkbox Visual Composer shortcode?

Tags: visual-composer

I have code multi checkbox here:

```
array(
        "type"        => "checkbox",
        "heading"     => esc_html__( 'Theme Data', 'my-theme' ),
        "param_name"  => "pr_name",
        "admin_label" => true,
        "value"       => array(
            esc_html__( 'Department', 'my-theme' ) => 'department',
            esc_html__( 'Salarry', 'my-theme' ) => 'salarry',
            esc_html__( 'Address', 'my-theme' ) => 'address',
            esc_html__( 'Degree', 'my-theme' ) => 'degree',
            esc_html__( 'Work time', 'my-theme' ) => 'time',
            esc_html__( 'End time', 'my-theme' ) => 'enddate'
        ),
        'std' => array('department', 'salarry'),
    );
```

Yes, this code not working. How to checked value default is: `department` and `salarry` ?

Where is wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use 'department,salarry' as the value of the 'std' key.

```
'std' => 'department,salarry',
```